# How to group dataframe rows into a list?

Tags: r, list, group-by

I have a dataframe df:

```
a b
A 1
A 2
A 5
B 5
B 4
C 6
```

I want to group by the first column and get second column as lists in rows:

```
a b
A [1,2,5]
B [5,4]
C [6]
```

Is it possible to do this in R using groupby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to create a `list` column use `I` after grouping by 'a' in `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(b ~ a, df, FUN = I)
```

If it is a string, then `paste` the elements of 'b'

```
aggregate(b ~ a, df, FUN = toString)
```

If it needs to be `paste`d in a specific format i.e. `[1, 2, 5]`

```
aggregate(b ~ a, FUN = function(x) sprintf("[%s]", toString(x)))
```

---

with `dplyr`, we can do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarise(b = list(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `paste0`:

```
aggregate(b ~ a, df, function(x) paste0("[", paste(x, collapse = ","),"]", collapse = ""))
  a       b
1 A [1,2,5]
2 B   [5,4]
3 C     [6]
```